# cannot declare variable " to be of abstract type "

Tags: c++, variables, inheritance, pure-virtual

I have a base class called "SHAPE" that only contains pure virtual functions where each method = 0.
The derived class of that base class is TRIANGLE. All of it's methods are derived from the base class SHAPE. I have closely inspected the code but I see no errors in the code. Why does the compiler keep on screaming at me that I cannot declare a variable that has a type TRIANGLE?

SHAPE.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

#include "POINT.h"


class SHAPE
{
    public:

        SHAPE();
        ~SHAPE();

        virtual bool isValid() const = 0;
        virtual double getArea() const = 0;

        virtual void set_sides() = 0;
        virtual POINT operator[](const int index) const = 0;
        virtual bool isInside(const POINT& other) const = 0;
};

#endif // SHAPE_H
```

TRIANGLE.h

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H

#include <SHAPE.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TRIANGLE : public SHAPE
{
    public:
        TRIANGLE();
        ~TRIANGLE();

        TRIANGLE(const POINT* arr);
        TRIANGLE(const POINT& first, const POINT& second, const POINT& third);

        bool isValid() const;
        double getArea() const;
        void set_sides();
        bool isInside() const;

        POINT operator[](const int index) const;

    private:
        POINT *points = new POINT[3];
        double sides[3];
};

#endif // TRIANGLE_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Render.h"
#include "GAME_SYSTEM.h"
#include "POINT.H"
#include "TRIANGLE.h"
#include "QUAD.h"

using namespace std;

Render* Render::RENDER = new Render();// ignore this

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Render* RENDER = Render::getInstance();//ignore this

    POINT a(3,3);
    POINT b(3,4);
    POINT c(4,3);

    TRIANGLE bob(a,b,c);//The problem is here
    printf("%i", bob[0].get('x'));//print the x value of the first point of triangle bob.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider trying a compiler with [more descriptive errors](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E3z85rbdY). Also use the `override` "keyword" to prevent accidents.

Comment: `isInside` has a different signature. As chris mentioned, using the `override` keyword would mention this pretty quickly.